# Is there a way to display a message when no valid input is displayed?

Tags: javascript, api, error-handling

Still pretty new at all this, but i was wondering if there is a way to display an error message if no valid input (404 message) is displayed.

The error message works if nothing is entered into the input box, but if the user doesn't spell for example 'London' correctly, the console displays a 404 message and i don't know how to display an error message for that, any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

```
$('#submitweather').click(function(){

    var city = $("#city").val();//declares variable name "city"

    if(city !== ''){ //if the input box is not empty

    $.ajax({

        //first part, web address. second part, global variable. third part, UK uses metric. fourth part, API key.
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+"&units=metric"+"&APPID=???",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "JSONP", //JSON with padding
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data); test worked
            var widget = show (data);

            $("#show").html(widget);
            $("#city").val('');} // empties input box when finished
            });
                    }   
        else if(city == ''){
            $("#error").html('Cannot Be Empty').fadeOut(10000);
        }
        else (){            
        }

});
```

});

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

Comment: So add an error handler to the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.ajax error handler which will catch not found or unauthorized and such, like this:

```js
$('#submitweather').click(function(){

  var city = $("#city").val(); //declares variable name "city"

  if(city !== ''){ //if the input box is not empty

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+"&units=metric"+"&APPID=???",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "JSONP", //JSON with padding
        success: function(data){
            
            // You could check the API response as well
            if (data.cod == 200){ // API specifies "cod" for the response code.
              $("#show").html(data);
              $("#city").val('');
            }else{
              $("#error").html(data.cod+" "+data.message).fadeOut(10000);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
         $("#error").html(textStatus+" "+errorThrown).fadeOut(10000);
        }
    });
  }   
  else if(city == ''){
    $("#error").html('Cannot Be Empty').fadeOut(10000);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="city" value="Londron" />
  <button id="submitweather">Check weather</button>
</div>

<h2>Result</h2>
<div id="show"></div>

<h2>Error</h2>
<div id="error"></div>
```